# Why does std::shared_ptr provide operator<<?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

`std::shared_ptr` provides `operator<<` which just writes out its address. There is no `operator>>` and only the address without the content is recorded. I am wondering in which cases it is useful.

Comment: So you can e.g. std::cout << ptr just like with a bare pointer

Comment: What would operator >> possibly do? Raw pointers don't support that operator either.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: `std::basic_istream` has an [`operator>>( void*& value )`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) for reading a raw pointer. That might be dangerous for a `shared_ptr`, although a `shared_ptr` can be constructed from a raw pointer, so it is not out of the realm of possible to create an `operator>>` for direct assignment to a `shared_ptr`. Though that wouldn't work if a custom deleter is needed, you would have to read the pointer first and then construct a new `shared_ptr` with it so you can specify a deleter.

Comment: I guess it's more for debugging/logging purpose rather than other causes. Having the address printed out might be helpful with some debuggers.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a potentially useful thing that `<<` does on a raw pointer.  It is safe, and it is what raw pointers do, and `shared_ptr` is supposed to be used to replace raw pointers in some situations.

In comparsion, `>>` would very rarely make sense.  Unlike a raw pointer, storing a pointer value in a shared pointer takes ownership of it.

I can `some_stream >> raw_ptr` and unless I do something with `ptr` nothing goes wrong; a bit strange, but nothing immediately breaks.

Doing the same to `shared_ptr` would only be safe in extremely esoteric situations.  In those situations, having to take a step where we first populate a raw pointer then load it into the shared pointer doesn't seem like an overly burdensome requirement.